# How can i check my running OS in VPS in Debian 8 64Bit

Tags: linux, debian

I have installed Debian 8 64Bit in my VPS. If I need to know what the bit of OS install in VPS command is `uname -a` and for OS information `lsb_release -a`.

But in Debian Linux distribution the `uname -a` command is working but `lsb_release -a` command is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `lsb_release -a` is not working, you need to install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-release
```

From https://packages.debian.org/jessie/lsb-release

> Linux Standard Base version reporting utility
>   The lsb-release command
>   is a simple tool to help identify the Linux distribution being used
>   and its compliance with the Linux Standard Base. LSB conformance will
>   not be reported unless the required metapackages are installed.

If you install lsb-core, lsb_release will output more information, but will also install more packages. So do additionally:

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-core
```

From https://packages.debian.org/jessie/lsb-core

> This package provides an implementation of the core of version 4.1 of
>   the Linux Standard Base for Debian on the Intel x86, Intel ia64
>   (Itanium), IBM S390, and PowerPC 32-bit architectures with the Linux
>   kernel.

Output without lsb-core:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.3 (jessie)
Release:    8.3
Codename:   jessie
```

Output with lsb-core package installed:

```
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.3 (jessie)
Release:    8.3
Codename:   jessie
```

Aditional packages installed for lsb-core (in my case):

alien at bc cups-bsd cups-client cups-common debhelper debugedit
  intltool-debian lib32z1 libc6-i386 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2
  libmail-sendmail-perl librpm3 librpmbuild3 librpmio3 librpmsign1
  libsys-hostname-long-perl lsb-security pax po-debconf rpm rpm-common
  rpm2cpio

Mind you these packages are normally installed by default, and someone (like me) too care of deinstalling them in your VPS.

I originally had none installed, at the end I made a compromise of having `lsb_release` but not `lsb-core` in order not to inflate the number of packages.

Comment: (I have the lsb-release package installed in my virtual servers, but not lsb-core)

Comment: Sound pretty good.
but if I installed it, then it consumes 80MB space on my VPS HDD and may also consume some ram space. so Is it wise to install this extra lsb-release for just one purpose.

Comment: exactly, lsb-core brings too many packages for a VPS farm

Comment: added these comments to the answer. They do not use up RAM space, as they are not daemons. The only "suspect" thing there is cups-bsd, but it can be deactivated. As I added to the answer normally in non-VPS machines these packages are installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
cat /etc/os-release
```

if these fail

```
ls -l /etc/*release*
```

and look and see the contents of those files

Comment: `/etc/issue` also usually has release/distribution information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hostnamectl`

```
 hostnamectl
```

The output:

```
  Static hostname: debian
       Icon name: computer
         Chassis: Laptop
      Machine ID: 4c983dae19f6403ca2c555c386cdeb14
         Boot ID: 3b399eb976d04569a8514a1dczdv4d81
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
          Kernel: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
    Architecture: x86-64
```